# How to insert rows in database even when inserting some records fail

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I am working on a spring batch and I want to be able to insert rows in the database even when it fails to insert some rows in it. I don't understand how can I keep the batch to update/insert rows in it when the job fails even if one record is not inserted.

I use insert/update query for pushing data in the database.

Comment: What are the errors you're getting on the ones that fail?  Why don't you just skip them?

Comment: @MichaelMinella How can I skip them, that is what I am looking for.. To skip the lines that are not read or inserted properly and then putting it in a log file finally.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ignore` keyword with both the inserts and the updates (`insert ignore ...`) to [downgrade most errors to warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-strict-comparison):

> Several statements in MySQL support an optional IGNORE keyword. This keyword causes the server to downgrade certain types of errors and generate warnings instead. For a multiple-row statement, IGNORE causes the statement to skip to the next row instead of aborting.

This way errors will not cause the overall inserts and updates to fail and you can retrieve any problems later by calling `show warnings`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very important to design non blocking jobs.
On batchs, the idea is to surround your persistant instructions with a try catch block and then logg the error or do something to trace what was wrong.
It makes you informed and non blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using spring batch you can probably use a `SkipPolicy`

```
public class InsertToDatabaseSkip implements SkipPolicy {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("InsertToDatabaseSkipLogger");

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exception, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
       if (exception instanceof SQLException) {
          logger.error(exception.getMessage());
          return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
  }
}
```

and then add it to your configuration

```
<batch:skip-policy>
   <bean class="com.skip.package.InsertToDatabaseSkip" scope="step"/>
</batch:skip-policy>
```

See : https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/skip/SkipPolicy.html